# How to set dns for applications deployed on kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, kubernetes-nodeport

I'm running my angular service with `Node IP` and `NodePort`. Now I want to set some dns name for my angular application. Where do I need to set the dns name for `Node IP` and `NodePort`? Is there any config file that I need to change?
example: 10.10.10.10/34781(my angular running)
expecting: myangular.deploy.com (How to set this?)

Im expecting to run my application with dns and not with IP and port.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the **ingress** to expose the service to internet.

**Ingress** is managed by the **ingress controller**, you can check this very simple official **k8s** example.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-example
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
```

Read more : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

However if you are looking for **internal communication** if your **Node** and **Angular** services running in same **K8s** cluster you can the **sericename** itself as the **internal** communication.